# TOAD Set Pagesize > Run as Script

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

If I run SQL in TOAD 11.0.0.116, and run it as a Script, it displays the output in the "Script Output" tab as raw text.

However, the display wraps after about 62 characters as you can see here:

[image: Screenshot showing how the text wraps]

I have messed about with setting the pagesize variable, to 0, and 200 and 2000 etc. but nothing makes any difference. Does anyone know if it is possible to prevent the text wrapping like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `set linesize` command. I have here the Toad version 9.5 and it works:

```
set linesize 500;
```

instead of `set pagesize`